# Regenerate composer.lock from vendor folder

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a magento 2 installation that has packages installed in vendor that are missing in composer.lock. i dont know if previous devs downloades packages manually.
If i try to install a new package, composer removes all these packages, and downgrades some magento 2 packages.
Is there any way to regenerate composer.lock and composer.json from installed packages from vendor folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If adding a new package removes other stuff from the vendor folder, then you have a problerm. Why not add such packages manually afterwards until you reach a stable state?

Comment: yeah that's what i'm doing while i fix it :(